# in Hyperion financial management which type of VB Script using in Rules 

Tags: vbscript, hyperion

I am Hyperion financial management learner . Some of my friends suggested VB Script for Hyperion financial management tool , In VB Script we are using  ,  ,  , but in Hyperion financial management tool in rules file starting with SUB,TESTCASE, ENDSUB  like this .

**Let me know which type of Scripting using in  Hyperion financial management tool .**

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12032_01/doc/epm.921/fdm_92000_scripting_guide.pdf) (please note, links to a PDF), your friends are correct, in that at least in version 9 it incorporated the Visual Basic scripting engine.

Answer (score 0):

It actually is VBScript. Oracle has been moving towards Calculation Manager (A visual rules designer) rather than VBScript files, but you still can use either Calculation Manager or VBScript files. Rules files use the `.rle` file extension. Here is a simple file that is a valid rules file:

```
Sub Calculate()
    'Runs when you CALCULATE an entity
End Sub

Sub Translate()
    'Runs when you TRANSLATE an entity
End Sub

Sub Consolidate()
    'Runs when you CONSOLIDATE an entity
End Sub
```